# Get components of string to array, including the string as individual components

Tags: nsstring

componentsSeparatedByString: of NSString is nice, but this time I need it to include also the components. So a hypothetic

```
NSArray* array = [@",hello,world,kominami," componentsSeparatedByAndIncludingString:@","];
```

would give me an array with components

- ,
- hello
- ,
- world
- ,
- kominami
- ,

Is there any such thing?

Answer (score 0):

What action are you attempting to perform with this method?

There are a couple of ways to address that, but you could start with an array literal, but that is immutable:

```
NSArray *strings = @[ @[ @"A", @"B", @"C" ], @[ @"D", @"E", @"F" ], @[ @"G", @"H", @"I" ] ];
```

However I would look at a mutable array to perform this.

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i < DESIRED_MAJOR_SIZE; i++)
{
[strings addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@""     
count:DESIRED_MINOR_SIZE]];
}
```